# Reading and writing mp3 files in C++

Tags: c, mp3

I am trying to read a mp3 file into a buffer, write it into another mp3 file and finally play it. The computer is running on Windows xp. But when i try to play the file, it throws an error message that says 'The input media format is not supported.' The input mp3 file size is 7.31 MB, and the output file size is 7.34 MB. The size of buffer after reading the input file is 7671370.

I have posted the code snippet for accomplishing the explained task. Please throw some light on the mistake here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>


int main () {

    FILE * iFile, * oFile;
    long lSize;
    char * buffer;
    size_t result;

    iFile = fopen ( "Ajn1.mp3" , "r" );
    if (iFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); }

    oFile = fopen ( "Ajn2.mp3" , "w" );
    if (oFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); }


    fseek (iFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell (iFile);
    rewind (iFile);


    buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); }


    result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,iFile);

    printf("%d\n",result);

    fwrite(buffer,lSize,1,oFile);

    fclose (iFile);
    free (buffer);
    printf("%d",lSize);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Try `fopen("Ajn1.mp3", "rb");` (and likewise for the file you write).

Comment: Use `"rb"` and `"wb"` as file modes to indicate binary files.

Comment: Just a note: the output file needs to be closed too.

Comment: Tagged C++ but you're using ancient C functions. Check std::fstream, it's easy to use and you don't need to worry about closing your files :)